# Store data into Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I was trying to store the data into excel but couldn't get success.

Below is the code so I wanted to store data in new excel which are having three columns:

1. Location
2. Latitude
3. Longitude

```py
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

df = pd.read_excel (r'D:\Python Code\Country List.xlsx')
print(df)
Country1 = df[['COUNTRY']]
print(Country1)
for i in range(len(df)):
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    location = geolocator.geocode(df.iloc[i,0],timeout=60)
    print(location.address)
    print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

Comment: where is your `.to_excel` call ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use openpyxl for Excel modification with python.
https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to write/read data in excel is https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
df = load_workbook(filename = 'D:\Python Code\Country List.xlsx')
for sheet in df: print(sheet.title) # see the sheet you want to read/write to
ws = df["your_sheet_name"]
print(ws['A1']) # print a cell
ws['A1'] = 'write to it'
```

It is really that simple.
Then the rest of the logic is the same.
And as it is a more a generic python pblm than a XLSX one I let you look at that :D.

tldr; You should take a look at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas function to_excel()

```
df.to_excel('new_excel_file.xlsx',index=False)
```